# Request header field ack is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response even the server already allowing it

Tags: java, node.js, spring, spring-boot, axios

I know this question already spreading all over the stackoverflow, but this one quite different.

I got an error when trying to hit a java API using axios, with below way,

```
axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/v1/homescreen")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Axios configuration were

> axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] =
> 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
> axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer
> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1N';
> axios.defaults.headers.common['Ack'] = 'MTIwNzIwMjBL==' ;

Already tried with `axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = application/json;`  and got the same error.

The error was

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/v1/homescreen'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Request header field ack is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Now in the server side i already configure it like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public SecurityConfig() {
        super();
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/cache/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated().and().authorizeRequests()
            .and().httpBasic();
    }

    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", 
        "Origin", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Authorization", "Ack", "ack", "ackwhatever", "goddamnack"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("DELETE", "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).antMatchers("/api/v1/login/*");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

even in the spring filter i put the header allowance

```
public class HttpRequestAuditFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("access");
    private static final int MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH = 10000;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        if ((request instanceof HttpServletRequest)
            && !(request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper)) {
            request = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
        }

        HttpServletResponse responseQ = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest requestQ = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        try {
            responseQ.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            responseQ.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            responseQ.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            responseQ.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, content-type, ack, Ack");
            responseQ.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, content-type, ack, Ack");

            if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(requestQ.getMethod())) {
                responseQ.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(requestQ, responseQ);
            }

        } finally {
            if (requestQ instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
                performRequestAudit((HttpServletRequest) requestQ);
            }
        }
    }

    public void performRequestAudit(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapper = WebUtils.getNativeRequest(httpRequest, ContentCachingRequestWrapper.class);

        String payload = "";
        if (wrapper != null) {
            byte[] requestBuffer = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (requestBuffer.length > 0) {
                int length = Math.min(requestBuffer.length, MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH);
                try {
                    payload = new String(requestBuffer,
                        0, length, wrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException unex) {
                    payload = "[Unsupported-Encoding]";
                }
            }
        }
        LOG.trace("{}|{}", payload, wrapper.getHeaderNames());
    }

}
```

When i try with curl i got the response even in the mobile app its work perfectly, only with browser that got error (the browser itself already --disable-web-security).

Any help and explanation will be apreciated.

Comment: Why is your security configuration class having the lowest precedence ? why do you have a spring filter to add the headers in response if you already configured spring security. You dont need the filter if you configure spring security with cors.

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan see i am trying everything to make this axios works, so my code a little bit chaos, but still readable though

Comment: Already tried with `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` still got the same error

Comment: Also provide @WebSecurity annotation here wth the configuration class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of providing the cors configuration class manually, let it be a bean and let spring take it up automatically, also remove the lowest order so that your configuration does not get overridden. Also remove the spring filter that you created to manually add the headers in the response as when configured correctly spring security will automatically add those headers in response. `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` can be used along with any `@Configuration` annotated classes but try like :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public SecurityConfig() {
        super();
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/cache/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated().and().authorizeRequests()
            .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", 
        "Origin", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Authorization", "Ack", "ack", "ackwhatever", "goddamnack"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("DELETE", "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).antMatchers("/api/v1/login/*");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work separate out the method level security configurations to another configuration class and keep the web security as a separate connfiguration.

Comment: Same, still got the same error.. `Request header field ack is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Comment: Can you try separating out the Spring security and the method leve security configurations into separate classes instead of one. I

Comment: See above code is working well with mobile app, postman, even curl.. why do we need to separate it?

Comment: Separating the config will let you  identify which aspect of the configuration is working and which is causing the issue , but that is not necessary , for some reason your cors configuration is not taken up by spring.Could you check your console to understand hwat all headers are added in the pre-flight request from react ?

Comment: Hmm actually this cors preflight issue previously happened in mobile app, after adding the  `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()` now its works in mobile, so i can say code above is taken up by spring... let me do full debug again